# Problemas com o botão no Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Boa noite. Estou aprendendo Front End e fazendo alguns exercícios online, e nesse código aqui eu deveria colocar a velocidade que um carro se movimenta, apertar o botão de verificação e concluir se ele está acima ou abaixo da velocidade permitida. Só que toda vez que eu vou apertar o botão ele nunca funciona. E não é só nesse exercício, mas em qualquer outro que eu faça o botão não funciona de jeito nenhum. Onde eu estou errando? Grato pela atenção.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
        <title>DETRAN</title>
        <style>
            
            
            
        </style>
    </head>

<body>
    <h1>Sistema de multas</h1>
    Velocidade do carro: <input type="number" name="txtvel" id="txtvel"> Km/h
    <input type="button" value="verificar" onclick="calcular()">
    <div id="res">
    
    <script>
    function calcular(){
        var txtv = window.document.querySelector('input#txtvel')
        var res = window.document.querySelector('div#res')
        var vel = Number(txtv.value)
        rest.innerHTML = `Sua velocidade atual é de ${vel} Km/h`
        
        if(vel > 60){ //condição simples
            rest.innerHTML += `Você está <strong>multado</strong> por excesso de velocidade`
    }else{
       rest.innerHTML += `Sua velocidade atual está na faixa permitida. Continue assim`
}
    rest.innerHTML += `Dirija sempre com o cinto de segurança!`
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Destacando o problema, caso alguém não tenha entendido a minha pergunta.

```
    <input type="button" value="verificar" onclick="calcular()">
```

Comment: declarou var RES no inicio mas  usou REST.innerHTML ="'.. EM ....var res = window.document.querySelector('div#res');.. acrescenta o T. ficando var rest = window.document.querySelector('div#res');... então teu código ira funcionar.

Comment: tera que verificar se mesmo o input em branco ao clicar no botão ira aparecer a mensagem.. tente fazer um if para se o campo estiver vazio apresenta uma mensagem que o campo nao pode estar vazio :)

Comment: Troquei e deu certo sim. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você errou  alguns nomes de variáveis, como *res* voce colocou *rest*, comentei o código para lhe ajudar a entender. Sugiro começar a usar o terminal do navegador para descobrir os erros, ajuda muito.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DETRAN</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sistema de multas</h1>
    Velocidade do carro: 
    <label for="velocidade"> 
    <!-- 
        Coloquei no label apenas por uma questão de novas regras do html.
        Não irá mudar nada no código.

    -->
        <input type="number" name="txtvel" id="txtvel"> Km/h
    </label>

    <input type="button" value="verificar" onclick="calcular()">
    <div id="res">

        <!-- Div precisa de fechamento -->
    </div>
    
    <script>
    function calcular(){
        var txtv = window.document.querySelector('input#txtvel')
        var res = window.document.querySelector('div#res')
        var vel = Number(txtv.value)

        // essa variável estava escrito errado, estava rest.innerHTML
        res.innerHTML = `Sua velocidade atual é de ${vel} Km/h`
        
        
        if(vel > 60){ //condição simples
            res.innerHTML += ` Você está <strong>multado</strong> por excesso de velocidade`
        }else{
           res.innerHTML += ` Sua velocidade atual está na faixa permitida. Continue assim`
        }
        res.innerHTML += ` Dirija sempre com o cinto de segurança!`
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```